# Refreshing data in session_start()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have two files php(index.php & data.php), the first send data to the second, and this it runs every one second and show the data.
The problem is the data is not updating

Maybe the code explains better

data.php

```
  <?php
  session_start();

  $xml = simplexml_load_file("file.xml"); // the contents of the file changes every second
  $json = json_encode($xml);
  $_SESSION['varname'] = $json;
  ?>
```

index.php

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript">
          window.setInterval(function() { 
        <?php 
        session_start(); 
        $json = $_SESSION['varname']; 
        ?>

        var newdata = <?php echo $json ; ?>;
    //code to show data

    }, 1000); 
          </script>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Call `session_start()` *prior* to beginning output in *index.php*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`session_start`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) must be called before any output (see notes in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)) which means you have to call `session_start` before any output:

```
<?php 
    session_start(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
      window.setInterval(function() { 
    <?php 
    $json = $_SESSION['varname']; 
    ?>

    var newdata = <?php echo $json ; ?>;
//code to show data

}, 1000); 
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually calling your data.php script from your javascript at all.  Your javascript is just static at this point (look at your output source), executing the same function over and over again with the same value for `newdata`.  You need to actually make an AJAX call to the data.php script to update the JSON.

Note that the session_start comments on this thread are important. This should be fixed as well, but that will not solve the fundamental problem you area having of wanting to use javascript to pull in the updated JSON data, but not having the value of `newdata` change because it is currently just static on your page.

Comment: How Can I make an AJAX please ?

Comment: but when I refresh the page I obtained the new data, soI must do that explicitly, the data does not change automatically

Comment: @SlimMils Just Google AJAX to get yourself started.  The concept is basically that your javascript will call your PHP script to get this additional data without having to have a page reload.  I would recommend using a javascript framework like jQuery to make performing AJAX call much easier, but only after you have worked through a few examples of doing it using pure javascript so that you can really learn what is going on.